# Best Way to Handle JSON response in Laravel

Tags: json, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.5

I use Laravel 5.5 and PHP 7, and I'm creating a form like this.

```
<form id="form" name="xxx" action="post">
  <input type="text" name="body_color[1][en]">
  <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I post data via Ajax, and I receive the following response from Laravel when I have an error.

> error: body_color.1.en: ["The body color.1.en field is required."]
>   success: false

If Laravel doesn't replace "[" and "]" with a dot, I can show an error message on the browser efficiently using jQuery.

```
$('#form *[name=body_color[1][en]]').after('input error!');
```

How can I show a simple error message in the web browser?

Answer (score 1):

With your jQuery requirement, a simple regex replacement should work for this case:

```
var str = "body_color.1.en"
str.replace(/\.(.+)\./, "[$1][") + "]" // returns body_color[1][en]
```

Or you could just split the string on the dots and rebuild it:

```
str.split('.')  // returns ['body_color', '1', 'en'];
```

There are many existing Javascript classes out there to handle the error responses, ex: https://github.com/spatie/form-backend-validation

Answer (score 0):

run your response through JSON.parse(response) and you should be able to use standard json dot syntax to step through the data.

```
var r = JSON.parse(response):
```

`console.log(r);`